# How do I download a pdf file onClick with react-pdf?

Tags: reactjs

I want to generate a pdf from the UI and download it. Been looking to the documentation but couldn't find how to implement I.e. `onClick={this.downloadPdf}`

here's the module reference:
https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf

It says:
**Save in a file**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactPDF from '@react-pdf/react-pdf';

ReactPDF.render(<MyDocument />, `${__dirname}/example.pdf`);
```

But this doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I think the example you have in your question is for server side rendering a PDF with Node.

Comment: I think it does not have api to download your pdf. Is your pdf from server or local. If it is local you can download it by import pdf from '../files/myfile.pdf' then <a href={pdf}>Click here for my pdf</a>

Comment: My pdf would be just a rendered component in UI. How do I make this work? Can I save it on the client side or it has to be a server and then the client can download it? would that work with firebase store?

Answer (score 31):

I have found below in their site [documentation](https://react-pdf.org/advanced#on-the-fly-rendering)

```
import { PDFDownloadLink, Document, Page } from '@react-pdf/renderer'

const MyDoc = () => (
  <Document>
    <Page>
      // My document data
    </Page>
  </Document>
)

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <PDFDownloadLink document={<MyDoc />} fileName="somename.pdf">
      {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download now!')}
    </PDFDownloadLink>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: When using the above answer, just remember to include `View` and `Text` inside the Document component. See here for more info: https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/317

Answer (score 9):

hi its working fine for me

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { PDFDownloadLink, Page, Text, View, Document, StyleSheet } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4'
  },
  section: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    flexGrow: 1
  }
});

const MyDoc = () => (
  <Document>
    <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>Section #1</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text>Section #2</Text>
      </View>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PDFDownloadLink document={<MyDoc />} fileName="somename.pdf">
      {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download now!')}
    </PDFDownloadLink>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```